# JS validate and submit a form in new window

Tags: javascript, forms, new-window, popup-blocker

I have a form that I validate with jQuery and if there are no errors, I submit the form. The form has `target="_blank"` so it opens in new window.

Some time the new window opens fine but some times it gets blocked by popup blocker in chrome.

I was submitting the form using JavaScript but learned that there needs to be a click event so it does not gets blocked.

I changed my code but the new window still some times gets blocked by the popup blocker.

Here is the code

```
$(".startBtnBox").click( function () {

  if( validate() ){
       var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

       var newTab = document.getElementById("submit_1st_step");

       evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

       newTab.dispatchEvent(evt);
   }
}
```

`submit_1st_step` is the id of the submit button for the form.

So once the form validates it creates a click event and executes it on the submit button.

I want to figure out why the form is submitted in new window successfully but some times it gets blocked by the popup blocker.

Is there a possibility that validation takes too long after the click so the new window event triggered by JS is blocked by the browser ?

Comment: Can you re-create the problem in a `jsfiddle`?

Comment: Is there a user action that is triggering `validate()` sometimes and other times not?

Comment: @brso05 yes there is click action. `$(".startBtnBox").click( function () { // above code in question goes in here // }`

Comment: as long as the event can be `bubbled` up to a user event it should work but if you try to programatically trigger an `event` without originating from a user event then it will probably block it...

Comment: why not just use the `$(".startBtnBox").click()` event to submit the form instead of using another button?

Comment: at the click event it needs to validate the form and once validation is successful it submits the form.

Comment: `$(".startBtnBox").click( function () { document.forms["myForm"].submit(); }`

Comment: If I remember correctly when I used this `document.forms["myForm"].submit();` it would get blocked every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82204/discussion-between-lafanter-and-brso05).